# How can I make the lyrics get bigger when I hover over it?

Tags: html, css

I made this flag with lyrics, and when the user hovers over it it should get bigger, but it's not working, I tried `.html:hover > .text`, `.all:hover >.text`:

`.html:hover > .text {
      color: red;
      font-size: 30px;
    }`

Any help is appretiated.

```css
.all {
  transition: 2s ease-out;
}
html:hover .all {
  background-image: #FF0000;
  transition: 1s ease-in;
  opacity: 0.1;
}
.text {
  font-size: 100%;
}
.text {
  font-size: 12px;
}
.html:hover > .text {
  color: red;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>musica.html</title>
</head>

<body>

  <img class="all" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/9a/Confederate_Rebel_Flag.svg/2000px-Confederate_Rebel_Flag.svg.png" style="position:fixed; width:100%;height:100% " />
  <center>
    <pre>
        <h1>Dixieland</h1>
      <div class="text">Oh, I wish I was in the land of cotton,
Old times there are not forgotten, (Alt Original: Cinnamon seed and sandy bottom,)
Look away, look away, look away Dixie Land.

In Dixie Land, where I was born in,
early on one frosty mornin', 
Look away, look away, look away Dixie Land. 

I wish I was in Dixie, Hooray! Hooray! 
In Dixie Land I'll take my stand
to live and die in Dixie. 
Away, away, away down south in Dixie. 
Away, away, away down south in Dixie 

Optional Verses

Ole Missus marry "Will the weaver"
Willum was a gay deceiver
Look away! Look away! Look away!
Dixie Land

But when he put his arm around 'er,
He smiled fierce as a forty pounder,
Look away! Look away! Look away!
Dixie Land

His face was sharp as a butcher's cleaver
But that did not seem to grieve 'er
Look away! Look away! Look away!
Dixie Land

Ole Missus acted the foolish part
And died for a man that broke her heart
Look away! Look away! Look away!
Dixie Land

Now here's a health to the next ole Missus
An' all the gals that want to kiss us;
Look away! Look away! Look away!
Dixie Land

But if you want to drive 'way sorrow
Come and hear this song tomorrow
Look away! Look away! Look away!
Dixie Land

There's buckwheat cakes and Injun batter,
Makes you fat or a little fatter
Look away! Look away! Look away!
Dixie Land


Then hoe it down and scratch your gravel,
To Dixie's Land I'm bound to travel,
Look away! Look away! Look away!
Dixie Land
        </div>
      </pre>
  </center>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `>` in CSS selector means that the `.text` element should be direct ascendant of the HTML. Furthermore there are no `hover` events on the html.

So you're better of adding `:hover` directive directly to `.text`:

```
.text:hover {
  color: red;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by updating your following style

from

```
.html:hover > .text {
      color: red;
      font-size: 30px;
    }
```

to

```
html:hover  .text {
      color: red;
      font-size: 30px;
    }
```

For reference - http://plnkr.co/edit/MZ4OneSGtJiGdBTeXTXh?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for helping me, I was struggling really hard